# A Very Odd Game

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy, game

Barry, John, and Caleb, all perfect logicians, were very bored one day and they decided to come up with a new game (they haven't got a name for that game yet). The rules were quite simple :

1. The first player gets to take either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 from the 40 available pens.
2. Then, the second player is also able to pick either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 from the remaining pens.
3. The third player is able to do the same
4. Repeat steps 1, 2 and 3 until the player who takes the last pen loses

Now comes the question :

Imagine you are Barry and whether Barry or the other players go first is entirely up to you.

Is it always possible to win at this game?

> Players aren't allowed to work together in this game

Comment: _"...assume all players are perfect logicians"_ All players or John?

Comment: Well John and the additional player. You just need to make a strategy as Barry to win @u_ndefined

Comment: Oh, and also, you didn't mention who goes first. Who goes first?

Comment: It is up to you to decide whether you or the other players go first as long as you can make sure that you win @u_ndefined

Comment: I think it is similar to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/picking-up-stones and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/20-coins-on-the-table

Comment: Well yes, but in my question players are allowed to pick either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 and another player is also added. Is this still considered as a duplicate? @nikki

Comment: Tbh, I'm also fairly new. So I don't know if it is considered a duplicate.

Comment: hmm, I might have to delete this question...

Comment: But doesn't the option that allows the players to choose more than 3 and the additional player make this different? @u_ndefined

Comment: What does a perfect logician do in a situation where he's sure that he can't win (e.g. 7 coins left, 3 players)?

Comment: Well whatever he does will result to his loss, so he will just randomly choose from 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5

Comment: Wait, just to clarify. In 3 players, there are 2 winners and only 1 loser, right?

Comment: Oh come on guys, I just spent more than an hour developing a strategy for the three player version, which OP says (in a comment to [@jafe's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/69510/36023)) is required for the tick, and now I cannot post it. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The *actual question* is definitely a dupe. But if Kevin wanted to open a new question for *the three-player version* then I don't see that anyone would object. (Unless it turns out that that's a dupe too; I haven't looked.)

Comment: just removed the first question. @GarethMcCaughan

Comment: @sedrick yes once there are 2 winners and 1 loser, the game stops

Comment: @KevinL, I've written a follow-up question to the bonus question: "if Barry gets to choose the seating order, which seat should he take, assuming that all the players are well known to be impartial, only trying to maximise their own chances of winning". Since it's originally your puzzle, you get the dibs to ask that question too, but only if you have a solution handy, of course :-) I actually have the complete text of that question ready and waiting in an editor, so just say so, and I'll post it myself.

Comment: That's actually a nice additional question so I guess you can go ahead and do so. Gonna try to come up with a solution to that as well :) @Bass

Comment: @KevinL, here it is: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69542/single-pile-nim-with-three-players

Comment: @KevinL, this was an interesting puzzle! I think that logic-ing it out as I have done below should suffice as a proof of my solution, but the extension to this will likely need computation.....

Comment: I know right. I asked all my friends this and they were completely puzzled @El-Guest

Comment: @KevinL take a look at my solution below. I personally don't think it's possible to force a win without collusion because with three players, you'd need to force one person to lose (and this can't be done without the two others working together.

Comment: @El-Guest I actually agree that forcing another player is the only way to win but one of my friends said that it is possible without collusion. Nevertheless, I guess I'll accept ur answer :)

Comment: @KevinL that's interesting -- in the without collusion case (Bass' question), it appears that somebody computed that there is no better than a 7/8 chance of winning from any position. It would be cool to see your friend's solution to this problem, if it's available too! Great question though! :D

Comment: The problem is that they are betting (around 10 dollars) to see if I can solve this :) @El-Guest

Comment: I'd definitely take a look at the solutions provided by Bass, jafe, and Mike Earnest in Bass' linked question. There's no way you can force a win without knowing what the other player will do; and there are too many "indifference points" where a player should be indifferent towards which player he can hinder. If you know that John hates Caleb and will do anything in his power to make Caleb lose, I'm pretty sure there's a perfect strategy (and I think I described my solution below). If John hates Caleb and Barry equally, there's not really much that Barry can do! :) @KevinL

Comment: I agree. I'll try showing ur solution to my friends. Hopefully they'll give me my 10 dollars :) @El-Guest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question as it is written (10AM, 8/14/2018), the solution is that

> there is no way to force a win for this game without collusion.

Based on my solution to @Bass's question [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69542/single-pile-nim-with-three-players),

> This game is usually won by "forcing" another player to take a specific candy (in this case, it's the 8th last candy, the 15th, 22nd, 29th, 36th). However, the only way to force another player to take that candy is to force the next player in line to take it. Based on my reasoning in the linked question, this strategy guarantees a win for the 3rd player (the player after the player you forced), but does not guarantee a win for you since the 3rd player can still screw you over. There is a maximum likelihood winning strategy (still to be found in @Bass' question), but it is not guaranteed - nobody's chances of winning will be 100% without collusion.

Answer (score 5):

> You go first and take 3. From here, you can move in sixes toward 1 – whatever number $n$ the other player picks, you pick $6-n$. After 12 moves, there's one pen left and it's the opponent's turn.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer. Figure out the bonus question and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the game correctly

> Then yes, it is possible for the first player to win always
>  Case 1: First player keeps picking 1, making the other player also pick 1 each time. Player 1 will pick the 39th pen, and player 2 the 40th.
>  Case 2: First player keeps picking 2, forcing the other player also to keep picking 2. Finally player 1 picks the 37th and 38th pens, while player 2 picks the 39th and 40th.
>  Case 3: First player keeps picking 3, forcing the other player also to keep picking 3. Finally player 1 picks the 35th, 36th and 37th pens, while player 2 picks the 38th, 39th and 40th.
>  Case 4: First player keeps picking 2, forcing the other player also to keep picking 2. Finally player 1 picks the 33, 34, 35, 36th pens, while player 2 picks the 37, 38, 39, 40th pens.
>  Case 5: First player keeps picking 5, forcing the other player also to keep picking 5. Finally player 1 picks the 31, 32, 33, 34, 35th pens, while player 2 picks the 36, 37, 38, 39, 40th pens.

Comment: Well you can't just make the other player choose the number you want. Assume they are logicians (I guess). I'll edit the question @nikki

Comment: Oh okay, I assumed second player was forced to pick the same number as 1st player

Answer (score 1):

For Bonus-

> Barry should choose to go last, and choose 13-n pens, where n is the sum of pens picked by the first two players, after 3 rounds, only 1 pen remains and player one loses, then he can beat the other player by @jafe 's method.

Comment: What if 13 - n > 5?

Comment: oh, didn't notice that, back to the drawing board i go..

Answer (score 0):

Bonus

> If there are 3 players, they can always conspire against Barry and make sure he loses. If Barry goes first, they just need to make sure that in every "round", 10 pens are removed. If Barry goes second, same thing (first player takes 4 then whatever Barry takes, third player takes 6 minus that number). If Barry goes third, first 2 players take 5 each, and it's as if Barry is now "first" with 30 pens left.

Comment: Lol. I didn't even consider that possibility. I'll clarify that players aren't allowed to team up

Comment: Wait never mind. I thought whoever took the last wins.

Comment: It's pens not coins

Comment: Oh whoops my bad lol